# session in multiple subdomains

Tags: php, session, authentication

I have a multiple domains like site.com and web.site.com.

I have already login system, but if i login in site.com, web.site.com don't know the login, because I'm using `session_start();`.
So, is there a way to "choose" or something else to do to all my subdomains to know that user is loged in?
Like google and youtube....

I tried to do it like browser automatically post the user sp. ID but i't doesn't work for sub-domains if you go back.

Thanks.

Comment: You're talking about the concept of "Single Sign-on" There are some really well established tools out there for that. Search around a bit and find the one that's right for your project.

Comment: Thanks. Now, i try some free open source SSO. Thanks again.